# Why does this Recursion code that returns not work?

Tags: java

I have been learning java for a few months now at school and we started recursions. Recursion where you just print stuff, void, are pretty simple, but I can't quite grasp ones that have returns. I just wrote a simple code that checked if something is less more than 50. I could've use num >= 50, but this is just a proof of concept. I will just return true if it is over 50 and false if less than 50. For some reason, it always returns false, even if it ran true before. How can I fix this?

```
public static boolean greaterthanfifty(int i, int counter) {
        if(i > 0 && counter == 50) {
            System.out.println("First if: i: " + i + " counter: " + counter);
            return true;
        } else if(i <= 0 && counter == 50) {
            System.out.println("2nd if: i: " + i + " counter: " + counter);
            return false;
        } else {

            greaterthanfifty(i - 1, counter + 1);
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " counter: " + counter);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You discard the result of your recursive call to `greaterthanfifty` and return false in the induction step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static boolean greaterthanfifty(int i, int counter) {
        if(i > 0 && counter == 50) {
            System.out.println("First if: i: " + i + " counter: " + counter);
            return true;
        } else if(i <= 0 && counter == 50) {
            System.out.println("2nd if: i: " + i + " counter: " + counter);
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " counter: " + counter);
            return greaterthanfifty(i - 1, counter + 1);;
        }
    }
```

because:

```
             else {
    
                greaterthanfifty(i - 1, counter + 1);
                System.out.println("i: " + i + " counter: " + counter);
                return false;
            }
```

here you are going to return anyway false.